# Ubuntu 20.04 started freezing often days after installation on Lenovo V14 AMD Ryzen 3 3250u

Tags: performance

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 (dual boot) on a new machine - Lenovo V14 AMD® Ryzen 3 3250u with Radeon graphics × 4, 64-bit, RAM 8GB (but only 5.6GB RAM is showing in the "info" tab so I guess 2gb is allocated to graphics).

After a few days Ubuntu started freezing very often, usually after I open some more apps or tabs. Firstly the buttons of apps stop working, then the mouse freezes as well and the only option is to restart using the power button.

I post here info from logs after one such freeze and reboot.

I'd be happy to provide any additional info as well.

[image: log]

[Long logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ukslGL0SThmWq9ZMFie54pkWdx7wdw7broz_bbst8ys/edit?usp=sharing)